# Can I log simulated IMC time in a simulator without a CFII?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, flight-simulator, logging, instrument-rating

I am working on my instrument rating under part 61. I need 40 hours of simulated IMC and 20 of those hours can be in a certified AATD simulator like a redbird. Do I need a CFII to sign off on those hours in the redbird or can I log those hours myself and count them towards my 40 hours of sim IMC?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I added the faa-regulations tag to your question; please *always* tell us which country or regulations you're asking about.

Comment: There is a difference between a Basic Aviation Training Device (BATD) and an AATD. You can log time for the instrument rating in the old-style BATD but cannot use it for maintaining instrument currency. Refer to AC 61-136B for details.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need an instructor. [14 CFR 61.65(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-B/section-61.65) (emphasis mine):

> Use of an aviation training device.  A maximum of 10 hours of
> instrument time received in a basic aviation training device or a
> maximum of 20 hours of instrument time received in an advanced
> aviation training device may be credited for the instrument time
> requirements of this section if -
>
> (1) The device is approved and authorized by the FAA;
>
> (2) **An authorized instructor provides the instrument time in the
> device**; and
>
> (3) The FAA approved the instrument training and instrument tasks
> performed in the device.

You may be thinking of maintaining IFR *currency* using a simulator. That doesn't need an instructor, per [61.57(c)(2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.57).

Comment: *You can log it, but it won't count towards a certification*

Comment: A subtle, detail, @RonBeyer. Subtle, but _very_ important!